# Fastest way to test matrix elements in python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, matrix

I want to create a matrix where the (i,j)th entry is the sum of the elements i:j of some ordered list L. I actually want to stop at the elementary where the sum exceeds the largest member of L.

For example, if `L = [2,3,5,7]`, the matrix would look like:

```
[ 2, 5, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 3, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 5, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 7 ]
```

I then want to scan through the matrix and find the largest number of consecutive members of the list that add up to another element in the list, if there is more than one of these sublists then I choose the one that has the highest sum. So in my previous example, the highest number would be 2, since 2+5=7 and 7 is in the list.

What is the fastest way to do this for very large lists? (millions of elements). I could do something like:

```
m = np.zeros(shape = (nmb, nmb))
for i in range(0, nmb):
    m[i, i:] = np.cumsum(L[i:])

print(m)
```

but I'm not sure how to stop the cumsum when the highest value in L is exceeded. In fact I really only need the upper triangle of the matrix, or really just the main diagonal and a few of the upper triangle diagonals as the cumulative sum exceeds the highest value in L much earlier than when exhausting the number of columns in the matrix.

**update**:

a bit faster:

```
m = np.zeros(shape = (nmb, nmb))
np.fill_diagonal(m, L)

for i in range(0, nmb):
    j = i + 1
    while  2*m[i,j-1]<L[-1]:
        m[i, j] = m[i, j-1] + m[j, j]
        j+=1
print(m)
```

seems like it is still slow to filter through and pick out the biggest streaks though, maybe i shouldn't be using a matrix with so many zeroes

Comment: Your edited code doesn't do exactly what you wanted, test it on your original  L

Comment: @jfish003 ah damn, need a better condition

Comment: **"...very large lists? (millions of elements)"** data storage is going to be a problem on a conventional PC.   Do you have some guarantee that the max element is a sum of a very small fraction of the elements, like <1%, <0.1%  ?  I'd check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: @f5r5e5d actually yes, I'm working with prime numbers, i'm trying to figure out an upper bound on the maximal number of elements though... as in, N represents the length of the list 1,...,N. and the list L is the number of primes <=N. so i want my code to be able to handle N ~ 30,000,000. in which case N is bigger than 1M

Comment: so your matrix will have size N^2 for N ~ 30,000,000? It seems to be a bit large

Comment: @PetarPetrovic hence why I asked the question on here...

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I went until I got to 10,000 elements (going much more starts pushing close to memory limits which then is an issue for speed itself) and I found that this was reasonably fast (less than 1 second on my machine)

```
import numpy as np
import time

Cl1 = time.time()
L = np.random.randint(1,100,10000)
nmb = np.size(L)
m = np.zeros(shape = (nmb, nmb))
np.fill_diagonal(m, L)


for i in range(nmb-1):
    j = i+1  
    if np.sum(L[i:j+1])<=np.max(L):
        m[i,j] = np.sum(L[i:j+1])  


Cl2 = time.time()
print(m)
print(Cl2-Cl1)
```